# Should my app use just one managed object context?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is it appropriate for my app to have several managed object contexts? I was going this route, (passing along my MOC from one instance of a UIViewController subclass to the next,) but I'm starting to run into EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors and I'm wondering if it could be related.

So, when do I want to use multiple ManagedObjectContexts, and (when) should I only use one?

**Edit:**

In my `UISplitViewController` based app, when deleting a row on my Master view, *only* after presenting a second view inside the main detail view, my detail view controller crashes on `respondsToSelector`, which I don't call ever.

**Edit 2:**

Basically, I have a master view and a detail view. In the detail view, the user presses a button. The button brings up a "new transaction" view. Instead of presenting the view modally, I manually add it to the detail view. If the user makes a change to the managed object context in this new view and then tries to delete the row in the master view, it causes a crash. If I present the same view modally, everything works just fine.

Furthermore, NSZombieEnabled says that a `respondsToSelector` method is being called on the (parent) detail view. I don't call that anywhere in my app. Could this be a memory issue? A threading issue? I don't explicitly create any new threads, but I don't know if there are any threads being created behind the scenes.

What might be the problem?

**EDIT3:**

This problem seems to get better. In my detail view, I also have a table, which, like the master view, uses an NSFetchedResults controller. When I delete the cell, I also hide the detail view, which causes it to be released. Releasing the detail view causes the app to crash. If I don't delete the detail view, the transactions in the detail view's table are deleted. (This is because I have Core Data set to cascade when an account is deleted.)

So, perhaps I have too many `NSFetchResultsController` objects? I believe that what is happening is follows:

When I delete a row, the NSFetchResultsController value changes and so it tries to fire the delegate method. However, the detail view has been removed and it's view controller deallocated. So, the delegate system fires a controllerDidChange method and crashes when trying to deliver the notification to the detail view.

How can I fix this?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS sometimes occurs if you share a managed object between two threads, but there could be other memory management issues. Try running with NSZombiesEnabled=YES in the simulator to see what object your app is trying to access.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits - In my splitview app, when deleting a row on my Master view, my detail view controller crashes on `respondsToSelector`, which I don't call ever. Should my views that create objects just directly access the delegate's ManagedObjectContext.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have one managed object context for your data model, and both your left-hand list view and your detail view share the same context object.  When you try to add a new managed object to the context in the detail view, then try to delete a row in the list view, you encounter a crash.  This isn't a threading issue, because you're not creating new threads yourself, so you shouldn't need more than one context here.  Is your left-hand list view handled through an NSFetchedResultsController?  If so, is it properly listening for context updates?

Comment: @BradLarson - What do you mean by "properly"? I'm implementing an empty `controllerDidChange` method.

Comment: @Moshe - You should fill out the `-controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` and other NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods in your list view so that it handles the addition and removal of rows caused by table edits or operations in other view controllers.  If not done properly, things can get out of sync and lead to artifacts in your table view or crashes (which can be hard to track down due to the way that table views animate on updates).  You can use boilerplate code for this: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/updated-navigation-based-core-data.html .

Comment: @BradLarson - Thanks! I've seen similar code in Apple's boilerplate, but I guess I didn't see the need for it.

Comment: Sounds like your table view is trying to redraw the cell of the item you've deleted. Another way to avoid this issue would be to simply call -reloadData on the tableview when you get a notification of the delete.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits I think so too, but I've gotten a little convoluted with the the notification passing between view controllers. The delete is triggered through the UITableView swipe and tap "delete" gesture, actually. I'm going to go over that code then.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits - I think you've nailed it, hang on...

Comment: @BradLarson - I've diagnosed the problem, thanks to @ImHuntingWabbits. My NSFetchResultsController is firing a method on the detail view after it's been removed from memory. How would I properly clean up the delegate?

Comment: @Moshe - If you're talking about the NSFetchedResultsController that belongs to the detail view, set its delegate to nil just before you release it in the detail view's -dealloc method.  This should be done for any table view or detail view that has its own NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking you should use just one, unless you need to access data from multiple threads, in which case you'll need one per thread.

You certainly shouldn't need to create one per UIViewController.

You might also want to re-think whether you should pass the whole managed object context to a UIViewController anyway - how about just passing it the model objects it needs to do it's job?

Comment: If I'm not creating one per view controller, how do I do data inserts and queries? Just define the methods on the app delegate, then should I pass in the data in a notification or something?

Comment: @Moshe: The same context can be shared by multiple view controllers, provided they're all operating in the same thread. Often, you don't even need direct access to the context -- managed objects know what context they're part of, so if you modify one it'll do the right thing. For example, you might add a 'person' object to a list of 'employees' just by accessing the 'employees' object. If you have a view controller that displays the list of employees, you can set it up just by giving it the 'employees' list -- you don't need to give it the context explicitly.

Comment: @Moshe, yes, see NSManagedObject's [-managedObjectContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/managedObjectContext) method.

Comment: @AndrewEbling - Thanks. I'll leave this question open a little longer until the comments up top are all done. (Resolving that part of the conversation.)